# How to draw these figures in the same line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

There are the figures and its code:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}          
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,fit,shapes.gates.logic.US, shapes.gates.logic.IEC, calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,0); 
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,3.5);
            \draw[thick,black] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,3.5);
            \draw [black, thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=1cm]
            node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
            \draw (1.8,0) node[anchor=north]{P};
            \draw (3.5,1.75) node[anchor=west]{Q};
            \draw (1.75,1.75) node[anchor=south east]{S};           
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof*{figure}{Inductive Power Factor}
            $\hspace{1in}$
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,0); 
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,-3.5);
            \draw[thick,black] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,-3.5);
            \draw [black, thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=-45, radius=1cm]
            node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
            \draw (1.8,0) node[anchor=south]{P};
            \draw (1.75,-1.75) node[anchor=north east]{S};
            \draw (3.5,-1.75) node[anchor=west]{Q};  
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof*{figure}{Capacitive Power Factor}
            \end{center}
\end{document}
```

How I am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of `captionof*`. You can put a simple node.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,fit,shapes.gates.logic.US, shapes.gates.logic.IEC, calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,3.5);
            \draw[thick,black] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,3.5);
            \draw [black, thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=1cm]
            node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
            \draw (1.8,0) node[anchor=north]{P};
            \draw (3.5,1.75) node[anchor=west]{Q};
            \draw (1.75,1.75) node[anchor=south east]{S};
            \node[below] at (current bounding box.south) {Inductive Power Factor};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \hspace{1in}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,-3.5);
            \draw[thick,black] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,-3.5);
            \draw [black, thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=-45, radius=1cm]
            node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
            \draw (1.8,0) node[anchor=south]{P};
            \draw (1.75,-1.75) node[anchor=north east]{S};
            \draw (3.5,-1.75) node[anchor=west]{Q};
            \node[below] at (current bounding box.south) {Capacitive Power Factor};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need `\captionof`, use `minipage`s

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes.arrows,decorations.pathmorphing, matrix,chains,scopes,positioning,fit,shapes.gates.logic.US, shapes.gates.logic.IEC, calc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,3.5);
            \draw[thick,black] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,3.5);
            \draw [black, thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=1cm]
            node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
            \draw (1.8,0) node[anchor=north]{P};
            \draw (3.5,1.75) node[anchor=west]{Q};
            \draw (1.75,1.75) node[anchor=south east]{S};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof*{figure}{Inductive Power Factor}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,0);
            \draw[thick,black] (0,0) -- (3.5,-3.5);
            \draw[thick,black] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,-3.5);
            \draw [black, thick] (1,0) arc [start angle=0, end angle=-45, radius=1cm]
            node [midway, right] {$\phi$};
            \draw (1.8,0) node[anchor=south]{P};
            \draw (1.75,-1.75) node[anchor=north east]{S};
            \draw (3.5,-1.75) node[anchor=west]{Q};
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \captionof*{figure}{Capacitive Power Factor}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]